# i keep get this error "Error: Command failed with ENOENT: ts-node prisma/seed.ts spawn ts-node" when i run npx prisma db seed

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, prisma

I really need help after I updated my prisma schema I got this error when I run `npx prisma db seed`

**Error: Command failed with ENOENT: ts-node prisma/seed.ts spawn ts-node**